# Transmitting a File Over Web Bluetooth

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, file-transfer

I'm developing a web app that has to transmit files over Bluetooth. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing that? Example code would be much appreciated. I can't find any good documentation online. Also, it must be able to run on mobile devices. I'm very new to JavaScript. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I would strongly advise against using bluetooth as a beginner (or in general at this time due to it being a WIP for many browsers):

> Web Bluetooth is NOT available for any mobile browser except Chrome & Opera for Android and Samsung Browser

The best resource is probably [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth) and the [specification](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth).

Something along the lines of:

```js
// Discovery options match any devices advertising:
// . The standard heart rate service.
// . Both 16-bit service IDs 0x1802 and 0x1803.
// . A proprietary 128-bit UUID service c48e6067-5295-48d3-8d5c-0395f61792b1.
// . Devices with name "ExampleName".
// . Devices with name starting with "Prefix".
//
// And enables access to the battery service if devices
// include it, even if devices do not advertise that service.
let options = {
  filters: [
    {services: ['<Your Device UUID>']}
  ]
}

navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options).then(function(device) {
  console.log('Name: ' + device.name);
  return device.gatt.getPrimaryService();
})
.then(function(service) {
  return service.getCharacheteristic('<Your Charachteristic UUID>');
})
.then(function(characteristic) {
  // Do something with the characteristic
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Something went wrong. " + error);
});
```

Comment: thanks so much for the help. Since this would not be able to run on apple devices, what's the best alternative? I considered making an app, but I really dislike Android Studio, and I couldn't find a way to design an iOS app for free. For what I'm developing, any form of file transfer works (even wired I suppose) as long as it doesn't use a wifi network (wifi frequencies interfere with other devices in situations where this app would be used)

Comment: @NicholasCarpenedo Bluetooth and WiFi utilize the same frequency range (2.4GHz) so that may cause issues - Though if you need an app you can checkout [react-native](https://reactnative.dev) and [react-native-ble-plx](https://blog.expo.io/so-you-want-to-build-a-bluetooth-app-with-react-native-and-expo-6ea6a31a151d) although for high interference environments I would go with wired connections since it allows for higher resistance to interference

Comment: I was under the impression that the frequency hopping nature of Bluetooth would help with interference. Does JavaScript have the ability to transfer files via a usb connection? It seems that a web app would be the most versatile way to develop this.

Comment: It really depends on the connected device - but there is a [USB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USB) also, though that is also not widely supported. Your best choice would be a semi-native application such as electron and react-native, etc.